# Scatter plot with horizontal lines representing averages with R and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

The below code produces a scatter plot with regression lines for each group. Instead of the sloped regression lines is it possible to plot horizontal lines that represent the average of each group's y values? I tried modifying the formula parameter to "y ~ 0 *x" but can't think of anything else that's obvious to use.

Thanks

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) + geom_point() + 
geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ x , se = F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the formula as `y ~ 1`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ 1)
```

[image]